# JSON format not displaying all model attributes (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I've run into a bizarre issue running Rails 4.2.7:  When I look at the HTML index view for a particular model, everything seems fine.  When I request the same data via JSON, I only get a subset of the attributes.

My index action is just:

```
def index
  @coverages = Coverage.all
end
```

If I call it with

`http://localhost:3000/coverages`

everything is there.  If I call it with

`http://localhost:3000/coverages.json`

I only get 7 of the attributes returned, in addition to the `:id`, `:created_at`, `:updated_at`, and a `:url` to the instance (e.g. `http://localhost:3005/coverages/1.json`).

Is the JSON method somehow truncating the attributes?  I never recall running into this before.

---

POSTSCRIPT:

I modified the index action to:

```
def index
  @coverages = Coverage.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :index}   
    format.json {render json: @coverages}
  end
end
```

and now I get all the attributes.  Probably I was violating Rails best practices by not including the explicit format statements, but I am still curious about my original result.

Comment: You might have some sort of serializer that's serializing the `@coverages` object. Look for something like `*.jbuilder`. If you're stumped there, could you put your code up on GitHub in its entirety so someone can take a peak? It could be a number of things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution I found (in the Postscript of the question) here in case it is useful.  Still an open question as to why the original configuration didn't work.

---

Modifying the index action to:

```
def index
  @coverages = Coverage.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :index}   
    format.json {render json: @coverages}
  end
end
```

solves the issue.